# Printing a crystal report in a loop using .NET

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report named EmployeeDetails.rpt which prints all the details for a particular employee in a formatted way.

Now i have new requirement, to print the same EmployeeDetails report for a list of employees.i.e

For each employee in the Employees list.

Print report EmployeeDetails.rpt

End

How can i realise the same, Does Crystal reports give any options to support such a report
Or i have to realise the logic in my .NET code ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the report an EmployeeID as param, then yes, you will have to loop the Employee List and reapply the Report Params for each new EmployeeID.